# AS3 / Flash - Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I know this is a common question, but I've looked through all of the others and couldn't figure out a solution for my problem.

I've debugged and found the offending line of code, but I'm not sure what exactly it is that's wrong with it or how to fix it.

Code below - the error is thrown when "enemy.movement();" calls the movement function in the Enemy class.  The first 2 lines of code(var xDist and var yDist) or specifically flagged.

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

public class zombiestandoffMain extends MovieClip 
{
    static public var enemy:Enemy;
    static public var player:Player;
    public var gameTimer:Timer;
    public var crosshair:Crosshair;
    public var army:Array;

    public function zombiestandoffMain() 
    {
        //enemy = new Enemy();
        //addChild( enemy );

        army = new Array();
        var newEnemy = new Enemy;
        army.push( newEnemy );
        addChild( newEnemy );

        player = new Player();
        addChild( player );

        crosshair = new Crosshair();
        addChild( crosshair );
        crosshair.x = mouseX;
        crosshair.y = mouseY;

        gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
        gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick );
        gameTimer.start();
    }

    public function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
    {


        var newEnemy:Enemy = new Enemy;
        army.push( newEnemy );
        addChild( newEnemy );

        crosshair.x = mouseX;
        crosshair.y = mouseY;

        for each ( var enemy:Enemy in army )  {

            enemy.movement();
        }



            //if ( player.hitTestObject( enemy ) ) 
            //{

            //}




    }

}
}
```

And the Enemy class:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.Event;


public class Enemy extends MovieClip 
{
    public var sideSpawn = int(Math.random() * 3)

    public function Enemy() 
    {

        if (sideSpawn == 0) {//top
            x = Math.random() * 800;
            y = 200;
            } else if (sideSpawn == 1) {//left
            x = -20; 
            y = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 800 - 200)) + 200);
            } else if (sideSpawn == 2) {//right
            x = 800 + 20;
            y = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 800 - 200)) + 200);
            } else { //bottom
            x = Math.random() * 800;
            y = 800 + 20;

            //(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + high - low)) + low);

        }
    }

    public function movement():void {


            var xDist = Math.abs(zombiestandoffMain.enemy.x - zombiestandoffMain.player.x);
            var yDist = Math.abs(zombiestandoffMain.enemy.y - zombiestandoffMain.player.y);

            if (xDist > yDist) {
                if (zombiestandoffMain.enemy.x > zombiestandoffMain.player.x)
                    zombiestandoffMain.enemy.x-=2;
                    else zombiestandoffMain.enemy.x+=2;
                    } else {
                    if (zombiestandoffMain.enemy.y > zombiestandoffMain.player.y)
                    zombiestandoffMain.enemy.y-=2;
                    else zombiestandoffMain.enemy.y+=2;


                }
        }   

}
}
```

My best guess is that the x and y coords for enemy are null - but I've tried inserting values for the coords and still get the same error.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You need to set `zombiestandoffMain.enemy` to an `Enemy` object.

Comment: Doesn't "static public var enemy:Enemy;" do this? If not, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Nope. You've just declared enemy, now you have to define it. Set enemy inside `zombiestandoffMain` to a new Enemy obect: `enemy = new Enemy();`

Comment: Thanks!  That got rid of the error...now I just have to figure out why the enemies still aren't moving, just spawning...

Comment: Please add your response as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only declared enemy, you must also define it. Set `enemy` inside `zombiestandoffMain` to a new `Enemy` obect:

```
enemy = new Enemy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's with the zombiestandoffMain you are referencing in the movement() method. I do not see any definition of it in the Enemy Class. if it is meant to be defined manually in the flash environment or somewhere make sure that this property is (zombiestandoffMain) is reference properly. Hope that helps

Comment: I set the enemy and player variables as static in the main constructor so that I could call them from other classes via mainclass.variable (only way I know of to access variables globally).